# BootstrapGridView shows no data on sorting/grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, devexpress

Everything works fine when I just assign the DataSourceID attribute to the  dx:BootstrapGridView like this:

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView ID="BootstrapGridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="GROUPID" 
    DataSourceID="dsGroupDetails">

  <Settings ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFilterRow="true" 
    ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowFilterRowMenuLikeItem="true" />

  <SettingsBehavior MergeGroupsMode="Always" 
     AutoExpandAllGroups="true" />

   <Columns>
     <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn FieldName="GROUPID" >
                </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
     <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn FieldName="DESCRIPTION">
                        </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>

</dx:BootstrapGridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGroupDetails" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT CUSTOMER_GROUP_M_ID AS groupId, CUSTOMER_GROUP_M_DESC AS description FROM CUSTOMER_GROUP_M m where CUSTOMER_GROUP_M_DESC like 'n%'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but when I try to assign the datasource and bind it on a click event like this:

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView ID="BootstrapGridView1" runat="server" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="GROUPID">

  <Settings ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFilterRow="true" 
  ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowFilterRowMenuLikeItem="true" />

  <SettingsBehavior MergeGroupsMode="Always" AutoExpandAllGroups="true" />

   <Columns>
     <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn FieldName="GROUPID" >
                        </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
     <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn FieldName="DESCRIPTION">
                        </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
   </Columns>

</dx:BootstrapGridView>
```

And here's the c# code:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object Source, EventArgs e)
  {
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT groupId , description FROM GROUP where description like 'n%'";
        cmd.Connection = OracleCon;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        BootstrapGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        BootstrapGridView1.DataBind();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

It works after the click event, but when I click the column header for sorting or try to drag it for grouping, it shows "No data to display"

Comment: Same here @Den.. Did you find any workaround?